# Input string was not in a correct format. in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I see everyday in my Elmah this error. How can fix this?

> Input string was not in a correct format. 
>   **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.
>
> **Source Error:**

```
Line 40:     {
Line 41:         String Pass = password.Text;
Line 42:         Int64 UserName = Convert.ToInt64(username.Text);
Line 43: 
Line 44:         if ( Convert.ToInt32(Session["FaildLoginTime"]) == 5)
```

> **Source File:** c:\Inetpub\vhosts\domin.com\my.domin.com\WebMaster\LoginMaster.master.cs
>   **Line:** 42
>
> **Stack Trace:**

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]

   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +11793873

   System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +133

   System.Convert.ToInt64(String value) +51

   WebMaster_LoginMaster.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\vhosts\domin.com\my.domin.com\WebMaster\LoginMaster.master.cs:42

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12

   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15

   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35

   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

Comment: You try to convert a string to Int64, if you try to convert something like KKK it will raise an exception... Convert.ToInt64() only works with strings containing numbers.

Comment: log the value of `username.Text`... Make sure it isn't an empty string or contain non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

At line 42: `Int64 UserName = Convert.ToInt64(username.Text);` you should make sure that `username.Text` returns a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Int64.TryParse` instead.

[Int64.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx)